# How to normalise a signal to a given peak value

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I using the function fread to read a speech file and then using plot(file) to plot the signal. How do I normalize the peaks to +/- 1? I cannot find a function online.

Comment: Just divide the signal with its `max(abs())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scale the peaks so that they belong to `+/- 1`, you may apply this transformation to ensure that the signal has its dynamic range to `[0,1]`:

```
out = (in - min(in)) / (max(in) - min(in));
```

`in` and `out` are the input and output signals respectively.  Once you have this, you can multiply the signal by 2, then subtract this result by 1 so that the dynamic range is finally `+/- 1`. Because this is a speech signal, this is one dimensional and so the final code is:

```
out = 2*( (in - min(in)) / (max(in) - min(in)) ) - 1;
```